# Get tile layer intensity at given zoom and longitude/latitude (Leaflet)

Tags: leaflet, tiles, latitude-longitude, overlay

I can display a tile layer as an overlay in Leaflet via an url of the form path/to/my/tile/layer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png :

```
my_overlay = L.tileLayer('http://path/to/my/tile/layer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 17,
minZoom: 9
});
```

I would like to be able to extract the value of this overlay (e.g. pixel RGB) at a given zoom level and longitude, latitude, or even better, the mean value in a disk centered at these longitude and latitude.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue today-- I needed to load each tile into a separate canvas element, then operate on each to pixel of each tile to transform the image.

Using `L.tileLayer.canvas` and [this example](http://johngravois.com/lerc-leaflet) from John Gravois I was able to grab each tile, access the pixels, and then invert the colors (inversion code from [this Mozilla Developer Network help page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)).

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do with the pixel values, but this should at least give you access to them.

I'm using an Esri ImageService of Toronto to test this approach:
http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Toronto/ImageServer

I've created Gists of the regular tiles ([raw](https://gist.github.com/mappingvermont/32e9b947fc7bf60c91cecd460fc7b0bf), [rendered](http://rawgit.com/mappingvermont/32e9b947fc7bf60c91cecd460fc7b0bf/raw/9d59cdf8681e942425fe36fc6a551117e757fa03/leaflet_canvas.html)) and the inverted tiles ([raw](https://gist.github.com/mappingvermont/c7056e7cd0f68af6f75c98d493ead337) and [rendered](http://rawgit.com/mappingvermont/c7056e7cd0f68af6f75c98d493ead337/raw/fa72354cf121b95af7af2e9bdcb2a0356e3324e3/leaflet_canvas_invert.html)).

Update: I've also created a Gist ([raw](https://gist.github.com/mappingvermont/1422f3b8ed56934fb2d02a9f93901e2b), [rendered](http://rawgit.com/mappingvermont/1422f3b8ed56934fb2d02a9f93901e2b/raw/442ca66372846414ac46afdd446db7a7b2fbcfb3/Read_rgba.html)) that actual captures the rgba value of the pixel as the mouse moves over it, and uses that value to change the color of a div. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Charlie! I'll check that out and get back to this post.

Comment: Hi @user49088- I've updated my answer to include a Gist that reads the value directly from the canvas (and, as prove of concept, changes the color of a div to match it). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but not trivial. A way to do it is to subclass `L.TileLayer` in such a way that each tile is wrapped in a `<canvas>` (like https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas/blob/master/src/BoundaryCanvas.js#L244 does), then attaching events to the canvases to fetch the [pixel value of a given pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667045/getpixel-from-html-canvas).

You might also run into [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS) issues when loading images into a canvas.

So not easy, but doable.